# jQuery constrain find/if to just one div and its children

Tags: jquery, if-statement, find, each, addclass

This question is simple, but the set-up's a bit complex. Please bear with me...

I have a big list of nested divs, like so:

```
<div id="ptosTable">

 <div class="elbox hue_vals">
  <a class="symtype1" href="#">
   <div class="sksym">E</div>
  </a>
 </div>

 <div class="elbox hue_domain">
  <a class="symtype1" href="#">
   <div class="sksym">L</div>
  </a>
 </div>

 <!-- ...plus 100 more just like these -->
</div>
```

There's also an existing script that clones each div (*.elbox*) to an entirely different div (*#pinsets*) on hover. [See below.]

Now, for each clone, I also want to add a css class to the clone div (only), dependent on a class variable in the source div.

**Examples**

1. If a source div has the class *hue_vals*, the class *symhue_vals* should be added to the .*sksym* subdiv of the clone (only).
2. Same for eight other variants: *hue_prod* to *symhue_prod*, *hue_found* to *symhue_found*, etc.

The following script almost does this for *hue_vals*---except that it seems to look for the *hue_vals* class in all divs, not just the one being cloned:

```
$('.elbox').hover(function() {
 $(this).clone().appendTo('#pinsets');

     // next three lines add the new class
 $(this).each(function(i) {
  if($('.hue_vals')){
   $('#pinsets .sksym').addClass('symhue_vals');
  }
 });

 $('#pinsets').show();
}, function() {
 $('#pinsets').hide();
 $('#pinsets').html('');
});
```

The result is that *symhue_vals* is added to every clone's .*sksym* div, whether the source div has a *hue_vals* class or not.

So I guess my question (at last!) is: how can I limit the script to looking for *hue_whatever* _only_ in the div that's being cloned?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var $clone;
$('.elbox').hover(function() {
    $clone = $(this).clone();
    var cls = $.trim($clone.attr('class').replace('elbox', ''));
    $('.sksym', $clone).addClass('sym' + cls + '');
    $clone.appendTo('#pinsets');
    $('#pinsets').show();
},
function() {
    $('#pinsets').empty().hide();
});
```

Comment: Nice! Appending is an elegant approach---and it works, as long as hue_whatever is the first class after .elbox in its div. The example I posted here is a bit simplified, however. In my live version the .elbox div has several other classes. It looks like your script appends "sym" to whatever class comes first in the cloned list. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var $clone;
$('.elbox').hover(function() {
  $clone = $(this).clone()
  $clone.appendTo('#pinsets');

     // next three lines add the new class
 $(this).each(function(i) {
  if($('.hue_vals', $clone).length){
     $('#pinsets .sksym').addClass('symhue_vals');
  }
 });

  $('#pinsets').show();

}, function() {

  $('#pinsets').hide().html('');

});
```

Comment: The clone works; however, I'm sorry to say that "symhue_vals" isn't written to the clone's .sksym class tag.